# NiFi - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: apache-nifi

I am seeing some weird error in my nifi cluster, i have a 3node secured nifi cluster and we have some custom library nars when we deploying in all nodes 2 nodes starting up without any issues but in one node i am seeing the below errors.

```
2017-04-20 23:43:34,516 ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Failure to launch NiFi due to java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.nifi.processor.util.StandardValidators.createControllerServiceExistsValidator(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/nifi/components/Validator;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.nifi.processor.util.StandardValidators.createControllerServiceExistsValidator(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/nifi/components/Validator;
```

Comment: Usually this means there are multiple conflicting versions of the same class on the classpath, have you added any JARs directly to NiFi's lib directory?

Comment: You also may want to check what is bundled in your custom NAR by looking at work/nar/extensions/<your-nar>/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/ and make sure you are not bundling nifi-api

Comment: @BryanBende Thanks for the reply.yes i have added in default lib dir. is there any way to deploy custom libs.

Comment: You should only be deploying a NAR file to the lib directory (not other JARs), the NAR should then bundle all the JARs it needs. Is that what you currently have?

Comment: sorry for the confusion i have added custom Nars to default lib directory not JARS. after adding custom Nars only i am facing this issue. 

and i have checked the below path its not bundling anythig related to api.
work/nar/extensions/<your-nar>/META-INF/bundled-dependencies‌​/

Comment: And why this error occurs in only one node the other 2 is coming up without any issues.

Comment: Most likely some nodes are getting lucky and loaded classes in an order that works. Can you post a listing of your lib directory and also a listing of work/nar/extensions/<your-nar>/META-INF/bundled-dependencies‌​‌​/ somewhere? maybe a gist (https://gist.github.com/) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142843/discussion-between-anish-kumar-and-bryan-bende).

Comment: If you isolate the custom nars from the the default ones, it is easy to troubleshoot such class loader issues. You can set additional lib directories using nifi.nar.library.directory. 

ref : http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#core-properties-br 

Example : 
nifi.nar.library.directory.lib1=/nars/lib1
nifi.nar.library.directory.lib2=/nars/lib2

Answer (score 2):

Did you try deleting nar/ folder under work/ directory ,add your nars to lib/ and restart NiFi ? Usually, NiFi expands the nar bundles during start up.

Also, are you extending any standard processors to build a custom NiFi processor ? In such case you might have to add a nar dependency.